# Modify label_attr field in Symfony 5 form builder

Tags: forms, symfony, formbuilder, symfony5

When building a form in symfony form builder changing the choice attribute can be done.
However, for the label attribute this doesn't seem possible.

Here is how i modify the choice:

```
$builder->add('type', EntityType::class, [
    'class' => Resourcetype::class,
    'multiple' => true,
    'expanded' => true,
    'choice_attr' => function (?Resourcetype $type) {
        return ['class' => $type->getSafeName() . '-parent parent' : $type->getSafeName()
        ];
    });
```

Is this possible for the label_attr field?

Comment: yes, it should work. did you try it? https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html#form-variables-reference

Comment: yes, doing the same or similar gives me this error: An error has occurred resolving the options of the form "Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType": The option "label_attr" with value Closure is expected to be of type "array", but is of type "Closure".

Comment: so... apparently, you cannot use a closure (e.g. `function () {...}` and must return an array only. `[ ... ]`

Answer (score 1):

*EntityType* doesn't provide option for modifying choice label attributes.
You should do it yourself.

## 1. Simple solution

Iterate over choices in templating engine, one by one and render it yourselves. Obtain entity from choice and set label attribute.

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
    {%- for choice in form.choices %}
        <div>
            {% set entity = form.choices.vars.choices[choice.vars.value].data %}
            {{ form_widget(choice) }}
            {{ form_label(choice, null, {
                label_attr: {class: 'test-' ~ entity.number}
            }) }}
        </div>
    {% endfor -%}
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

## 2. Clean solution

Create custom type extending *EntityType*:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/create_custom_field_type.html

Create new option in type definition allowing closures e.g. "choice_label_attr" and pass closure to view:

```
// src/Form/Type/CustomEntityType.php
namespace App\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;

class CustomEntityType extends AbstractType
{
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setRequired('choice_label_attr');
    }
    
    public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
    {
        $view->vars['choice_label_attr'] = $options['choice_label_attr']
    }

    public function getParent(): string
    {
        return EntityType::class;
    }

}
```

Extend template for choice type:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_themes.html#applying-themes-to-all-forms

Use "choice_label_attr" callback inside extended template:

```
{% use "bootstrap_4_layout.html.twig" %}

{% block custom_entity_widget_expanded -%}
    <div {{ block('widget_container_attributes') }}>
        {%- for child in form %}
            {{- form_widget(child) -}}
            {{- form_label(child, null, {class: choice_label_attr(form.choices.vars.choices[child.vars.value].data), translation_domain: choice_translation_domain}) -}}
        {% endfor -%}
    </div>
{%- endblock custom_entity_widget_expanded %}
```

More info: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/5.x/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form/bootstrap_4_layout.html.twig

Usage example:

```
use App\Form\Type\CustomEntityType ;

$builder->add('type', CustomEntityType::class, [
    'class' => Resourcetype::class,
    'multiple' => true,
    'expanded' => true,
    'choice_attr' => function (?Resourcetype $type) {
        return [
            'class' => sprintf('%s-parent parent', $type->getSafeName()) : $type->getSafeName()
        ];
    });
```

**Solution 2. is written from head and can contain some bugs but I hope you get the idea.**

Both solution are using Twig and Bootstrap 4 form layout, but it is not requirement.