# Modify label_attr field in Symfony 6 form builder

Tags: css, class, symfony, checkbox, label

I can change the class of my inputs, but not for my labels.
How can I change class of my dynamics labels .
I can't when I use 'label_attr', because it's a type Closure.

```
$builder
        ->add('skill', EntityType::class, [
            'class' => Skill::class,
            'query_builder' => function (SkillRepository $r) {
                return $r->createQueryBuilder('i')
                    ->orderBy('i.color', 'ASC');
            },
            'label' => 'Mes compétences',
            // input OK !
            'choice_attr' => function (?Skill $color) {
                return $color ? ['class' => 'color_'.$color->getColor()] : [];
            },
            // ERROR
            'label_attr' => function (?Skill $color) {
                return $color ? ['class' => 'color_'.$color->getColor()] : [];
            },

            'attr' => [
                'class' => 'btn'
            ],
            'choice_label' => 'name',
            
            'multiple' => true,
            'expanded' => true,
        ])
```

An error has occurred resolving the options of the form "Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType": The option "label_attr" with value Closure is expected to be of type "array", but is of type "Closure".

```
            // ERROR
            'label_attr' => function (?Skill $color) {
                return $color ? ['class' => 'color_'.$color->getColor()] : [];
            },
```

Comment: The `label_attr` option doesn't allow closures, only array values. But you should have access to the "current" `Skill` entity during form building anyway: `'label_attr' => $skill ? ['class' => $skill->getColor()] : [],` and don't need a closure. If you want to update the label class dynamically based on the selected `Skill` option you will have to use frontend scripting.

Comment: duplicate, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65410145/modify-label-attr-field-in-symfony-5-form-builder